# MongoDB to return assoc array of results

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My collection has object with the following form

```
{'id':2, 'name':'john', 'avatar':'img.png'},
{'id':3, 'name':'chriss', 'avatar':'img2.png'}
```

After i query mongo, i want to get the following results

```
{'2': {'id':2, 'name':'john', 'avatar':'img.png'}, '3':{'id':3, 'name':'chriss', 'avatar':'img2.png'}}
```

Is it possible to do this with mongo or do i have to iterate over the results to get this form ?

Comment: U have to iterate the result to form the desired JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try iterating over the results using the [**`find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find) cursor's [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach) method as follows :

```
var obj = {};
db.collection.find({}, {"_id": 0}).forEach(function(doc){
    obj[doc.id.toString()] = doc;
});
printjson(obj);
```

Or using the [**`map()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/) method:

```
var mapped = db.collection.find({}, {"_id": 0}).map(function(doc){
    var obj = {};
    obj[doc.id.toString()] = doc;
    return obj;
});
printjson(mapped);
```

**Output in both methods**:

```
{
        "2" : {
                "id" : 2,
                "name" : "john",
                "avatar" : "img.png"
        },
        "3" : {
                "id" : 3,
                "name" : "chriss",
                "avatar" : "img2.png"
        }
}
```